# How to get Individuals set of Object Property with OWLAPI

Tags: java, owl-api

Please, I want to parse the following ontology with java program using OWLAPI.

```
   <ObjectPropertyAssertion>
        <ObjectProperty IRI="http://onto1#creator"/>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="Mark1"/>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="Car1"/>
    </ObjectPropertyAssertion>
    <ObjectPropertyAssertion>
        <ObjectProperty IRI="http://onto1#creator"/>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="Mark2"/>
        <NamedIndividual IRI="Car2"/>
    </ObjectPropertyAssertion>
```

The output:

- Mark1 --> Car1
- Mark2 --> Car2

Thank you in advance for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first extract the individuals in your ontology, and then ask `OWL API` to find the values of the object properties assigned to these individuals:

```
    Set<OWLNamedIndividual> inds=localOntology.getIndividualsInSignature();
    for (OWLNamedIndividual ind: inds){
        System.out.println(ind.getObjectPropertyValues(localOntology));
    }
```

Comment: For OWLAPI version 4, check EntitySearcher - many methods declared in OWLEntity have been moved there.

Comment: Hi! Is there any short way to retain the individual according to its DataProperty in OWL API? For instance, if I want retain individual which is unknown for me, but I know that it should have the DataProperty (let's say orderNumber = 1).
I think that iterating through a Set<OWLNamedIndividual> inds takes more time.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can use an OWLDataFactory as

```
OWLOntologyManager manager = OWLManager.createOWLOntologyManager();
OWLDataFactory factory = manager.getDataFactory();
 Set<OWLNamedIndividual> inds = localOntology.getIndividualsInSignature();
    for (OWLNamedIndividual ind: inds){
        System.out.println(ind.getObjectPropertyValues(factory.getOWLObjectProperty(IRI.create("Put the iri of the property here")), localOntology));
    }
```

Although keep in mind `System.out.println(ind.getObjectPropertyValues(factory.getOWLObjectProperty(IRI.create("Put the iri of the property here")), localOntology));` returns a `Set<OWLIndividual>`

 This has the benefit of looking for exactly the property you want to use as opposed to all the properties on a particular individual.

Comment: Thank you very much, yes I have used this solution becuase it returns a set of individuals of a specific object property.